# Does NSMutableArray actually count the items every time its count method is called?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, performance

Because of cocoa design patterns, the name of the instance method `count` in `NSMutableArray` is ambiguous; it could either return a saved variable `count`, or it could count the items in the array each time it's called, and return that (cocoa dictates that a method that simply returns the value of a variable `foo` be `foo`, not `getFoo`). **Does Objective C's `NSMutableArray` actually count the items every time its `count` method is called, or does it return the value of a pre-calculated variable?** If this were Java, I'd look at the source code, but I can't find the source code for `NSMutableArray`. I looked at the API, and all it said was this:

> Returns the number of objects currently in the array.

Since there was no context, I can't tell if that means it does any calculations inside it or not.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is based on `CFArray` (and they're toll free bridged) so you can expect similar implementations. You can view the source of `CFArray` at http://opensource.apple.com

Comment: Everyone with good sense would use an ivar to count the objects.

Comment: @JackLawrence Here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.15/CFArray.c

Comment: @JackLawrence @JacobRelkin thank you, but I don't see a `count` _method_ in there...

Comment: C Function: `CFIndex CFArrayGetCount(CFArrayRef theArray);` returns `array->_count`. Notice the toll-free bridge call in the first line of the implementation as well: `CF_OBJC_FUNCDISPATCH0(__kCFArrayTypeID, CFIndex, array, "count");` While this doesn't make and promises about `NSArray`, it's usually a safe bet to assume that they work the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSArray` declares a private ivar `_used` that appears to hold the count of the array. Using `object_getInstanceVariable()` you can verify that in the case of the concrete subclass `__NSArrayM`, this variable is incremented and decremented as objects are added and removed.

I used the following program, a Mac OS X Foundation command-line tool, to verify this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *anArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSLog(@"anArray's concrete class is %@", [anArray class]);
        UInt64 used = 0;
        for (NSString *toAdd in @[@"o", @"m", @"g"]) {
            object_getInstanceVariable(anArray, "_used", (void **)&used);
            NSLog(@"array = %@, used = %lld", anArray, used);
            [anArray addObject:toAdd];
        }
        for (NSString *toRemove in [anArray copy]) {
            object_getInstanceVariable(anArray, "_used", (void **)&used);
            NSLog(@"array = %@, used = %lld", anArray, used);
            [anArray removeObject:toRemove];
        }
        object_getInstanceVariable(anArray, "_used", (void **)&used);
        NSLog(@"array = %@, used = %lld", anArray, used);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program produced the following output:

```
2013-01-31 17:40:15.376 Array[10173:303] anArray's concrete class is __NSArrayM
2013-01-31 17:40:15.378 Array[10173:303] array = (
), used = 0
2013-01-31 17:40:15.378 Array[10173:303] array = (
    o
), used = 1
2013-01-31 17:40:15.379 Array[10173:303] array = (
    o,
    m
), used = 2
2013-01-31 17:40:15.379 Array[10173:303] array = (
    o,
    m,
    g
), used = 3
2013-01-31 17:40:15.380 Array[10173:303] array = (
    m,
    g
), used = 2
2013-01-31 17:40:15.380 Array[10173:303] array = (
    g
), used = 1
2013-01-31 17:40:15.380 Array[10173:303] array = (
), used = 0
```

Answer (score 7):

As you have correctly noted, there is no guarantee that it will behave one way or the other.

In practice, though, `-[NSArray count]` is a constant-time operation. You can confirm this yourself by creating a small array and a large array and benchmarking the time it takes to get their counts. It would be pretty silly to have an O(n) `count` method on the core array classes like this.

Comment: In the current implementation (and, I would expect, all future implementations), `NSMutableArray` (via `CFArray`) simply has a `count` ivar that stores the count as a number, so no recalculation is necessary.

Comment: You can also look at the private ivars at runtime using the objc runtime library.