# In NSDictionary, is it faster to check count of an NSArray object via it's -count method or have a seperate key-value pair that contains the count?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Just a thought question (not even a big deal but piqued my curiosity).

Say I have an `NSDictionary` with 2 key-value pairs.

1. First key-value is an array of 100 or 1000 or 10000 (or any number of) dictionary objects.
2. Second key-value is a string object that is maintained to accurately store the count of the array (this can be an `NSNumber` object but lets keep it `NSString` to be in the `JSON` spirit).

so, something like:

```
{
    "keyValues": [
        {
            "key_1": "value_1"
        },
        {
            "key_2": "value_2"
        },
        ...
        ...
        {
            "key_N": "value_N"
        }
    ],
    "keyCount": "N" //where 'N' 100 or 1000 (basically the count of the array)
}
```

Now, my question is, which is more efficient (even if by a very small margin)

1. `int count = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"keyCount"] intValue];`
   or
2. `int count = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"keyValues"] count];`

NOTE: this is just a basic example so please bear with me.

Comment: NOTE: don't worry about efficiency. If you are really curious, benchmark it. -- Apart from that, I'd say that you should use the right tool for the task, so **just call `-count`** and don't hack around with nonsense things such as storing a duplicate of the count... please, just **don't.**

Comment: I don't but i have worked on client API's that provide such a key-value pair in the JSON response (these JSON responses are huge and everywhere I see them providing the count as a sub key-value pair)

Comment: (1. just noticed your username, it's awesome!) 2. That's too bad. I still don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why is it "JSON spirit" to store a number as a string?

Comment: @MartinR: actually i meant to say that my JSON response for `count` comes as a string object. (they have used boolean and int values for other keys but the count is always string... for me.

Comment: Whenever you duplicate data (for example keyCount and the number of elements in keyValues), there's the possibility that the numbers don't match, so you have to check them, and if they are different, then you are in trouble. So best case they match and your code is a lot slower because you had to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already parsed the JSON: According to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637259/does-nsmutablearray-actually-count-the-items-every-time-its-count-method-is-call), `count` is constant for `NSMutableArray`, so `count` should be at least as efficient in terms of processing time. It is definitely more efficient in terms of memory and more importantly, using count is not redundant and easier to maintain.

If you don't want to parse the entire JSON, things look different of course. To only get the count of objects, you don't need to create the array. Storing the count separate gives you the count with `O(1)` complexity, parsing the array is `O(n)`. For large arrays this can make noticeable difference.

Comment: true that. less overhead, non-redundant, easier to maintain which is why i was wondering why anyone would want to add extra workload if it gave no advantage. maybe just for uniformity of some kind.

Comment: @staticVoidMan In some cases you might only (or initially) be interested in the count. You wouldn't have to parse the entire JSON in this case. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So please tell us how you avoid parsing the entire JSON? With code that is actually rock solid?