# How expensive is the NSArray count method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am in a situation that I need to get the items in an array and time is sensitive.  I have the option of using a separate variable to hold the current count or just use NSMutableArray's count method.

ex:  `if (myArray.count == ... )`  or `if (myArrayCount == ...)`

How expensive is it to get the counting of items from the count method of an array?

Comment: Better to use  if (myArray.count == ... ) or if (myArrayCount == ...)

Comment: Getting the `count` of an `NSArray` is not expensive. Don't worry about it. If, later, you run into a performance problem in your app, use Instruments to find the cause(s).

Comment: And the cause won't be accessing the `count` property.

Comment: You should make your question more specific. You wrote "How expensive is it to get the counting of items from the count method of an array?"  which doesn't include any details that you wrote in the title: "Getting array items count or using another variable to keep track"

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is, there is no difference in speed, so access the count of the array as you wish my child :)

Comment: This is due to an automatic compiler optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Fetching `NSArray`'s `count` method is no more expensive then fetching a local variable in which you've stored this value.  It's not calculated when it's called.  It's calculated when the array is created and stored.

For `NSMutableArray`, the only difference is that the property is recalculated any time you modify the contents of the array.  The end result is still the same--when you call `count`, the number returned was precalculated.  It's just returning the precalculated number it already stored.

Storing count in a variable, particularly for an `NSMutableArray` is actually a worse option because the size of the array could change, and access the count in this variable is not faster whatsoever.  It only provides the added risk of potential inaccuracy.

The best way to prove to yourself that this is a preset value that is not calculated upon the `count` method being called is to create two arrays.  One array has only a few elements.  The other array has tens of thousands of elements.  Now time how long it takes `count` to return.  You'll find the time for `count` to return is identical no matter the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

As a correction to everyone above, NSArray does not have a count property. It has a count method. The method itself either physically counts all of the elements within the array or is a getter for a private variable the array stores. Unless you plan on subclassing NSArray and create a higher efficient system for counting dynamic and/or static arrays... you're not going to get better performance than using the count method on an NSArray. As a matter of fact, you should count on the fact that Apple has already optimized this method to it's max. My main ponder after this is that if you are doing an asynchronous call and your focus is optimizing the count of an NSArray how do you not know that you are seriously doing something wrong. If you are performing some high performance hitting method on the main thread or such... you should consider optimizing that. The performance hit of iterating and counting through the array using NSArray's count method should in no way effect your performance to any noticeable rate.

You should read up more on performance for NSArrays and NSMutableArrays if this is truly a concern for you. You can start here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637259/does-nsmutablearray-actually-count-the-items-every-time-its-count-method-is-call)

Comment: While it is technically correct that `count` is not a property, but indeed a method, it's incorrect to suggest that this value is calculated each time the `count` method is called on the array.  This most definitely is not the case.

Comment: Read my comment above. As noted, I provide that it is either counted or reads from a private variable. I also provide a link leading to this information. This behavior can change over time under different circumstances, so I note both possible ways. This is why it's a method and not a readonly variable. Either way, the Swift way will perform differently lol.

Comment: The method does not count the members of the array.  It accesses a variable that has already been calculated (when the array's size was last modified).

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you're suggesting that it is possible under some circumstances for the `count` method to actually take the time to calculate the value that should be returned.  With a straight yes or no answer, is this what you're suggesting?  If it is, you're wrong.

Comment: Also as noted, unless you want to write a new dynamic C array with higher efficiency with dynamically creating arrays, keeping index counts and such, you should not be focusing on the count method's time to perform it's functionality as an optimization. That, out of everything, is one of the last things you should look at. Even Facebook wouldn't have looked at that when dispatching drawing their custom animations and core graphics to a different thread under tight constraints.

Comment: And now I have no idea what you're talking about.  This question has nothing to do with anything in your last comment.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you're suggesting that it is possible under some circumstances for the count method to actually take the time to calculate the value that should be returned. With a straight yes or no answer, is this what you're suggesting? If it is, you're wrong. <--- I'm am providing the answer that at any given point in time (per apple's Objective-C updates) that this could be a functionality. I am not stating that this is current functionality. Once again, this shouldn't even be a focus for you ... at all. I've already provided a link for YOU to read how this works

Comment: @nhgrif, if you don't understand what I just said you should be focusing on how to optimize your code. My overall point (yet again) is that you should not receive any noticeable performance hint by calling NSInteger count = [array count];. If this effects your program in a time sensitive manner, you need to re write your program. If I was you, I'd look up GCD.

Comment: I'm not the person who asked the question.  I offered an answer.  And your answer has nothing to do with the question.  Your answer seems more like a comment.  The question is about the efficiency of the `count` method versus storing it as a variable, and you're reading between the lines, offering all sorts of assumptive conjecture and not actually directly answering the question directly asked.

Comment: My answer is as direct as it gets. You're not going to get better functionality than the count method unless you have a serious understand of comp science. The question noted that there was time sensitive functionality being performed and he wanted to optimize it by optimally getting the count for an NSArray. I'm replying with the answer, you shouldn't, you're not going to, and you're looking at the wrong thing. If you're going to argue this with me and don't understand this that is your problem.

Comment: He's not trying to rewrite the `count` method or optimize the count method.  He's wondering whether it's better to call it early and store it in a variable for later use or if `count` is just as fast as accessing the value he previously stored in the variable.  He's not trying to compare Apple's `count` method to one he's going to try writing himself.  He's comparing the speed of the method to the speed of pre-storing the value and fetching it from a local variable.  Your answer doesn't even remotely address this.

Comment: In fact, the fact that your answer suggests that `count` might actually calculate the size of the array as the method is called makes your answer very misleading and actually suggests that the questioner SHOULD be prefetching this value and storing it in a local variable so he can just access it from here later when it's time sensitive, but in reality, this is no more efficient then just calling `count` because calling `count` in fact DOES NOT calculate the size when it is called.  It only returns the precalculated value that the `NSArray` object stores.

Comment: And link-only answers aren't really acceptable on StackOVerflow either (not that your answer is, but you just suggested that that would've been an acceptable answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the item**s** then getting the count is *not* time critical. You'd also want to look at fast enumeration, or using enumeration with dispatch blocks, especially with parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Asa's is the most correct answer. I misunderstood the question.

Asa is right because the compiler will automatically optimize this and use the fastest way on its own.

---

TheGamingArt is correct about NSArray being as optimal as could be. However, this is only for obj-c.

Don't forget you have access to c and c++ which means you can use vectors which should be only 'slightly' faster considering it won't use obj-c messaging. However, it wouldn't surprise me if the difference isn't noticeable. c++ vector benchmarks: http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

This is a good example of Premature Optimization (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). I suggest you look into GCD or NSOperations (http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Comment: The code is the same, the compiler is the optimization ^^